# How to assign current date to a date field in odoo v8?

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

I wanted to assign the current date to a date field 'start_date' in the following code:

```
calendar_obj.create(cr,uid,
             {'name' : rec_res.act_ion,
              'user_id' : rec_res.asgnd_to.id,
              'start_date' : lambda *a:datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y'),
              'stop_date' : rec_res.due_date,
              'allday' : True,
              'partner_ids' : [(6,0, [rec_res.asgnd_to.partner_id.id])]
             },
context=context)
```

How to set or assign the current date value to the *start_date* field ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Date field includes a `today()` method, just for cases like this:

```
'start_date': fields.Date.today(),
```

Of course you need to import `fields` first:

```
from openerp import fields
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import time

'start_date':time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

Answer (score 2):

**python datetime – Date/time value manipulation.**

**Purpose:**    The datetime module includes functions and classes for doing date and time parsing, formatting, and arithmetic.

**Available In:**   2.3 and later

Use the datetime class to hold values consisting of both date and time components. As with date, there are several convenient class methods to make creating datetime instances from other common values.

```
'start_date' : datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')


import datetime

print 'Now    :', datetime.datetime.now()
print 'Today  :', datetime.datetime.today()
print 'UTC Now:', datetime.datetime.utcnow()

d = datetime.datetime.now()
for attr in [ 'year', 'month', 'day', 'hour', 'minute', 'second', 'microsecond']:
    print attr, ':', getattr(d, attr)
```

Result:

```
Now    : 2015-08-14 16:27:51.475070
Today  : 2015-08-14 16:27:51.475462
UTC Now: 2015-08-14 10:57:51.475585
year : 2015
month : 8
day : 14
hour : 16
minute : 27
second : 51
microsecond : 475645
```

**Formatting and Parsing**

The default string representation of a datetime object uses the ISO 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.mmmmmm). Alternate formats can be generated using strftime(). Similarly, if your input data includes timestamp values parsable with time.strptime(), then datetime.strptime() is a convenient way to convert them to datetime instances.

```
import datetime

format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"

today = datetime.datetime.today()
print 'ISO     :', today

s = today.strftime(format)
print 'strftime:', s

d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, format)
print 'strptime:', d.strftime(format)
```

Result:

```
ISO     : 2015-08-14 16:32:23.914699
strftime: Fri Aug 14 16:32:23 2015
strptime: Fri Aug 14 16:32:23 2015
```

Answer (score 1):

Try just

```
'start_date' : '%m-%d-%Y' % datetime.today(),
```

or

```
'start_date' : datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y'),
```

Comment: I tried and I am getting this error -  'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: I modified my answer, check it now. How did you declare the attribute `star_date`?

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

current_date = fields.Date(string='Date',default=datetime.now())

current_date.strftime("%d-%M-%Y") // strftime function use for the Date Format
```

Comment: your second line won't work as it is going to affect the current date at which the module was imported.