# Why am I getting the error: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'now'?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, odoo-8, odoo

If I run the method

```
from datetime import datetime
from timedelta import time 

def action_retbook(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None): 
    dt = datetime.date.now() 
    todaydate = datetime.strptime(dt, "%y/%m/%d") 
    x=6 
    cr.execute("""update rmkbook_issue set dt_of_return ='%s' where id= %s """ %(todaydate, x)) 
    return
```

I get the error `'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'now'`. Why?

Comment: hi @Hunter Stevens, the problem was in my code that arise at the line--> dt=datetime.date.now()..... and it get removed as wrote ----> dt=datetime.now()

Answer (score 3):

You can run the method now() like this:

```
dt = datetime.now()
```

You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965470/how-to-assign-current-date-to-a-date-field-in-odoo-v8/31965626#31965626) as well

Comment: tnxz... it works.... but now i got a error as---->>>"""ValueError: "must be string, not datetime.datetime" while evaluating"""" for the line          todaydate = datetime.strptime(dt, "%y/%m/%d")....

Comment: Try `datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')`

Comment: You can also use the method `write` to make the update or you can use the api of the 8 version if you are developing in Odoo v8

Comment: now i got error ---> ValueError: "syntax error at or near ")" ..... update rmkkbook_issue set dt_of_return = '2015/08/14' where id= (22,)......... As i wrote code ----> –

Comment: def action_retbook(self, cr, uid, ids,context=None):   todaydate=datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")      book_ids = context.get('active_ids', [])         for t in book_ids: cr.execute(""" select row_id from rmkbook_return_temp where id = %d """ %(t))                     x= cr.fetchone()         cr.execute("""update rmkbook_issue set dt_of_return ='%s' where id= %s """ %(todaydate,x))                return

Comment: hey ChesuCR, plz help me, i tried it to solve by different cases but no used..... The date format in my database postgres is "%Y-%m-%d"... and i am using it same to  my code....the other value x is integer......  (in a update query)...

Comment: When are you running that method? Are you using Odoo v8?

Comment: How did you declare the field `dt_of_return` field?

Comment: You should use the [orm methods](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html).

Answer (score 0):

I believe

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.now()
```

Works.. in python 3.9.7

Comment: I am getting this error: AttributeError: 'method_descriptor' object has no attribute 'now'

Comment: @LdM if you `import datetime` then yeah, you will see that error